# Create curved gradients with `Paint` and `Canvas`

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics

I am looking to dynamically create (bezier) curves in Android using `Canvas` and `Paint`. I can easily do nice curves with `setStrokeWidth` or doing a more complex polygon/path.

But how can I make the gradient follow the curve like in this example? `LinearGradient` in either direction would not give the same feel.

[image]

In some parts of the curve there is a narrower gradient as well.

Is it made by some inner shadow or maybe just redrawing lots and lots of curves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid curving the gradient is not possible using the **built-in gradient** classes (`LinearGradient`, `RadialGradient`, `SweepGradient`). It's possible to draw lots of curves, but that would basically mean writing the curved gradient yourself. :)
(And the shading of the surface looks a bit even more subtle to me, resembling a 3D render.)

Comment: Thanks. So you're thinking its a 3D render of some sort?! Its from an Android app which does it in real time I believe. I like the effect and thought of using it in an app. I was thinking of layering different techniques, like doing several curves, then blur that, then overlaying the top part, but its not going to be as good and definetly not as fast...  

Will see if more answers come in before I mark as answered.

Comment: Oh, is this animated in that app? If so, then I would suspect it uses a custom 2D drawing library or a 2D / 3D game engine. If it's a still image, then it's probably a render, or a retouched bitmap made in Photoshop, saved as a raster image. There are techniques to create similar artistic effects like this procedurally, for which you can find lots of examples in the demoscene. I'm just saying it's not made by a single built-in Android gradient.